# multidimensional array conversion is not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge, array-unique

Very frustrating moment and could not figure out and finally decided to move and ask to Geeks about solution.

Okay, Here is the problem.

I have below array and need to convert it by replacing repeating records from `array` and merge is as shown below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Index] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [content] => content 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [page_number] => 25
            [book_id] => 1
            [tag_id] => 3,2,4
            [need_review] => no
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:36:45
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:36:45
        )
        [Tag] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => three
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:32:13
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:32:13
        )
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Book 1
            [description] => book one
            [ordervalue] => 0
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:22:26
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:22:26
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Index] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [content] => content 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [page_number] => 25
            [book_id] => 1
            [tag_id] => 3,2,4
            [need_review] => no
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:36:45
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:36:45
        )
        [Tag] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => two
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:31:58
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:31:58
        )
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => book 1
            [description] => book one
            [ordervalue] => 0
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:22:26
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:22:26
        )

    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [Index] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [content] => content1
            [user_id] => 1
            [page_number] => 10
            [book_id] => 2
            [tag_id] => 1,2,3
            [need_review] => no
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:32:17
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:32:17
        )
        [Tag] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => three
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:32:13
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:32:13
        )
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => book2
            [description] => book two
            [ordervalue] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:24:04
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:24:04
        )
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [Index] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [content] => content1
            [user_id] => 1
            [page_number] => 10
            [book_id] => 2
            [tag_id] => 1,2,3
            [need_review] => no
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:32:17
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:32:17
        )
        [Tag] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => two
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:31:58
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:31:58
        )
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => book2
            [description] => book two
            [ordervalue] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:24:04
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:24:04
        )
    )
)
```

I want to convert this array into below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        'Tag' => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => two
            [user_id] => 1
            [status] => active
            [created] => 2013-06-27 12:31:58
            [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:31:58,
            [Book] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => book2
                [description] => book two
                [ordervalue] => 2
                [user_id] => 1
                [status] => active
                [created] => 2013-06-27 12:24:04
                [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:24:04
                [Index] => Array
                (
                    '0' => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [content] => content1
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [page_number] => 10
                        [book_id] => 2
                        [tag_id] => 1,2,3
                        [need_review] => no
                        [status] => active
                        [created] => 2013-06-27 12:32:17
                        [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:32:17
                    ),
                    '1' => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [content] => content 2
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [page_number] => 25
                        [book_id] => 1
                        [tag_id] => 3,2,4
                        [need_review] => no
                        [status] => active
                        [created] => 2013-06-27 12:36:45
                        [modified] => 2013-06-27 12:36:45
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and so on.

What i have tried?

```
$newindexes = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < count($indexes);$i++ )
{
    $newindexes[$i]['Book']          = $indexes[$i]['Book'];
    $newindexes[$i]['Book']['Index'] = array();

    for( $k = 0; $k < count($indexes);$k++ )
    {
        if($indexes[$i]['Book']['id'] == $indexes[$k]['Book']['id'])
        {
            $newindexes[$i]['Book']['Index'][] = $indexes[$k]['Index'];
        }
    }
}
```

and added `$newindexes = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $newindexes)));` at the end for removing duplicates but still not working.

Spent almost 4-5 hours but could not figure it out.

Please guys take a look and give me some correction in my code or provide me a helpful link.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should start by writing out our business logic rules- - ie: If an index is the same for two books, only use information from the first.

Comment: @JacobS please demonstrate it...

Comment: Well -- are all entries going to be in order, ie: Book ID 1, Book ID 1, Book ID 2, Book ID 3? Will all other information, except the "index", be the same? All of these things influence the "problem" you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a less robust answer that I would give to do what you ask, provided that all tag ids, book ids, and index ids are unique:

```
foreach($indexes as $index){
    $tagid = (int) $index['Tag']['id'];
    $bookid = (int) $index['Book']['id'];
    $indexid = (int) $index['Index']['id'];
    if(!isset($newindexes[$tagid])) {
        $newindexes[$tagid]['Tag'] = $index['Tag'];
    }
    if(!isset($newindexes[$tagid]['Tag']['Book']) || !isset($newindexes[$tagid]['Tag']['Book'][$bookid])) {
        $newindexes[$tagid]['Tag']['Book'][$bookid] = $index['Book'];
    }
    if(!isset($newindexes[$tagid]['Tag']['Book'][$bookid]['Index']) || !isset($newindexes[$tagid]['Tag']['Book'][$bookid]['Index'][$indexid])) {
        $newindexes[$tagid]['Tag']['Book'][$bookid]['Index'][$indexid] = $index['Index'];
    }
}
```